# Jquery onClick slow page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, typo3

I think my jquery ajax page loading is a bit slow. When I click my href with an onClick handler sometimes it doesn't response and I have to doublelick? How can I avoid this?

```
     <a target="_blank" class="arrow" href="javascript:void();" 
            onclick="f(\"value",\"value\");return false;">
                <div class="teaser">
                  <h3></h3>
                  <p class="subheadline"></p>
                  <hr class="divider">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
                <img height="353" class="img" src="example.jpg" width="374">
      </a>
```

Maybe it's because of the empy h3 and p tags? It feels a bit sluggish??

My function f is:

```
function f (url, id)
{
  var btn = $(this);
  if (btn.data('running'))
     return;

   $j('#tx #singleview').empty();
   btn.data('running', true);

   url="http://"+url+"index.php?id="+id+"&eID=tx";
   url_stack.push(url);

   $j.getJSON(url, function(json) {

    $('#container').css({
      "z-index" : "-100",
      "margin-left" : "148",
      "top" : "-800"      
    })

   $('#container').animate({
      "opacity": "0.0",
      "top": '+=800'
    }, 900, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });

   var singleview = $j('#tx #singleview');
   singleview.css({
     "position": "relative",
     "top": "-800px",
     "height": "800px"
   })
   singleview.append($j("#singleviewTemplate").tmpl(json).css({
     "visibility": "visible",
     "position": "relative"
     }));
   singleview.animate({
     opacity: 100.0,
     top: 0
   }, 900, function() {
     // Unset it here, this lets the button be clickable again
     btn.data('running', false);
   });      
 });
}
```

Comment: Empty tags shouldn't make a difference to the speed. What is the code of the `f()` function?

Comment: As you have written it, you have unescaped quote marks inside the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using the `onclick` attribute like that at all with jQuery.

Comment: `onclick="f("value","value");return false;"` should not be parsed correctly at all. Look at the quotation marks.

Comment: @lanzz: Do mean binding is better? It's in my template file?

Comment: @FelixKling: This is a stackoverflow typo. My function works but feels a bit sluggish???? I've also many database queries in my getJSON function. Maybe this slows down but I don't understand why I need sometimes a doubleclick or more click to fire?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @lanzz: No. I can't copy and paste into jsfiddle? How does this work? Do I have to write my code again?

Comment: Of course you can copy&paste to and from jsfiddle, the same way you normally do it.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah. Ok. Context-Menu in virtual machine doesn't work. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnTPQ/2/ but I don't think it helps understanding my problem?

Comment: BTW: I've a masonry jquery plugin on this div? Can it be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FireBug` or something else to check the response times from the server, but definitely you should start your question with specifying it's TYPO3.

Bare `eID` in some cases can consume about 700ms to render simplest output (accent for 'bare' word). In case when in your extension you have a lot of data from DB + some table `joins` rendering quite simple result set can be really slow. It can be of course improved, but first you have to determine where the problems lays.

We had last time such problem where paged results from only 5k records took ~30 seconds to render sorted items of 50 items per page for the JS grid (shock), after some simple tweaks we finished with 500ms per result page. It was definitely about our wrong query in `TYPO3` extension and AJAX had just to wait and I thin that you should search there at the begin.

*edit:*

To make sure that's long times lays at the TYPO3 side you should also create a `static file` containing some sample data set (similar to the one expected from TYPO3) and check how does it behaviour.

Comment: I have only a simple sql query in my ajax request but because I need to render all kinds of CType elements I need to initialize a cOBj in my response. I didn't know it's possible anyway?

Comment: Depending on your needs it's sometimes better just to create custom `pageType` and make sure it's lightweight: then you haven't to initialize such things like cObj manually, of course you need to avoid reading the whole TS, best by setting your plugin on the separate tree branch and clearing settings from your root page as much as possible.

Comment: I have thought about that but I don't think it's possible with a pageType? How would you get a json back with a pageType without using a Typo3 hook or something? My repsonse time with eID is only 776 ms. I don't think a pageType Json response can be faster? It's also easier with eID.

Comment: Of course it's possible - you can put on that page only one thing: your own extension rendering anything you want - also Json. However ~700ms is quite good timing, IMHO there's no need for 'better' solutions while it's stable. the `pageType` approach would be better if you need more data from TYPO3 - like data of logged user, parsed `rootline` etc.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://antwerpes.it/tutorial-typo3-als-ajax-seite/2011/11/? I wonder if the cObj of this response (the $content variable) contains all CType content elements of the specific page? This would be a bit easier for me. Currently with my eID solutions I need to call each CType function for a CType manually like this $cObj->IMGTEXT(...), or $cObj->MENU, or $cObj->RECORDS, this is a bit a pain in the ass.

Comment: It really depends on your needs and it's hard to consider anything with in-comment discussion, however it's sometimes easier in extensions to put somewhere on the tree and render it as cObj->CONTENT
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/7/#id783193

Comment: I don't understand? With the cOBj->CONTENT on a pagetree you would still get the whole pageobject? I don't need the cOBj->CONTENT, too, because when I want raw data I can bypass all Typo3 functions and fire a simple SQL query in me eID script? Because I need to render MENU and IMGTEXT CoBj a cObj->CONTENT wouldn't help me? BTW. the page is http://wwww.chihoang.de.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of experiment I was able to speed it a bit:

1. I'm firing my ajax getjson loading later when the animation is finished.
2. I have merged many Jquery animate css append functions together

   ```
   function singleview (url, id)
   {
   var btn = $(this);
   if (btn.data('running'))
     return;

   var c = $('#container');
   var s = $j('#tx #singleview');

   s.empty();
   btn.data('running', true);

   url="http://"+url+"index.php?id="+id+"&eID=tx";

   if (url_stack.length == 0 && url_back.length > 0)
   {
     bak = url_back.pop();
     url_stack.push(bak);
     url_back.push(bak);
     url_stack.push(url);
   } else
   {
     url_stack.push(url);  
   }

   c.css({
     "z-index" : "-100",
     "position": "absolute",
     "left" : "140px",
     "top" : "0px"
   }).animate({
     "position": "relative",
     "opacity": "0.0",
     "top": "+=600px",
     "left" : "140px"
   }, 900, function() {
     // Animation complete.
     $j.getJSON(url, function(json)
     {
       s.css({
         "position": "absolute",
         "top": "-600px",
         "height": "600px",
         "left" : "140px"
       }).animate({
         "opacity": "100.0",
         "top": "10px",
         "left" : "140px"
       }, 900, function() {
         // Unset it here, this lets the button be clickable again
         btn.data('running', false);
       }).append($j("#singleviewTemplate").tmpl(json).css({
         "visibility": "visible",
         "position": "relative"
       }));
    });      
   });
   ```

   }